# How to share properly a jupyter docker to host

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to access a jupyter run on a docker (windows) on my host. When running the regular command :

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v ~:/home/jovyan/workspace jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
```

I receive the address where I should be able to access the notebooks:

```
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-6-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://(be1b837f3804 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=0b2a6eaec3aae87xc2c04....
```

I can access it on my host (windows) when using 127.0.0.1 but not using the other address. My goal is ultimately to access this address from another local computer. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Suppose your host ip is `192.168.1.101`, then you mean use `http://192.168.1.101:8888/?token=0b2a6eaec3aae87xc2c04....` on `192.168.1.101 computer` also not work?

Comment: I meant using http://be1b837f3804:8888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`be1b837f3804` is the host name of your container, this could not be accessed by clients out of container.

In fact when you use `127.0.0.1:8888` to visit your service, you are still not directly visit the container. It will first visit the host's network namespace (127.0.0.1), then because you did port binding (-p 8888:8888), so all traffic to host's 8888 will route to container's 8888 port.

So, as I said in comments, if you want to visit the container's service from other client, you had to specify the host's ip, e.g. docker host's ip is `192.168.1.101`, then on other pc, open next to visit:

```
http://192.168.1.101:8888/?token=0b2a6eaec3aae87xc2c04....
```

You may also want to have a look for [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)